# How to move all css files in footer in mageno 2.2

Tags: magento-2.2.5

In `Magento 2.2.5`, I have to load all `CSS` files in footer rather than header(as Magento do by default).
Please anybody can suggest me solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Anybody there, can help me into this.

Comment: Why you move CSS in the footer?

Comment: Hello Devidas, as per site optimization i wanted to load content first then CSS.

Comment: you can minify CSS and JS

Comment: Yes, i already did, but wanted to call css at body end/footer.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139107/magento-2-move-the-javascript-to-the-end-of-the-body

Comment: you can try as same CSS

Comment: @VijayGupta. Upgrade to 2.3.3, it has that feature

Comment: @Manjunath, Let me try thank you.